# How to compute an estimate of the expected value of a stochastic random variable in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, linear-regression, expectation, random-variable

In the section on LSTD in SuttonBarto's book on RL, there is a proof on convergence of semi-gradient TD(0) using a linear function approximator.

[image: Point of convergence]

[image]

Later on they estimated A and b as

[image: Estimate of A and b]

I was under the impression that to calculate an estimate of E[Rt+1*xt], you would have to run multiple episodes till time t and then average those samples but how are they able to estimate **A** and **b** using samples from times 0 to t-1 instead?

Comment: Could you please confirm the edition, chapter/section and equation numbers you are looking at?

Comment: @NeilSlater Section 9.8 LSTD and equation 9.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TD(0) learning your are using a one-step bootstrapping equation:

$$ V(s_t) = r_{t+1} + V(s_{t+1}) $$

So in order to calculate the value of state $s_t$ you only do a one step look ahead and you bootstrap with the value of the next state $s_{t+1}$ (read more [here](https://pi-tau.github.io/posts/actor-critic/#online-advantage-actor-critic)).

Your value of each state is approximated by a function with weights $w$, and you optimize the weights with gradient descent. You try to make the old value $V_{w_{old}}(s_t)$ closer to the new value $V_{w}(s_t) = r_{t+1} + V_{w_{old}}(s_{t+1})$ and the objective that you optimize is the least squares objective:

$$ L =\frac{1}{2} \Big(V_w(s_t) - r_{t+1} + V_{w_{old}}(s_{t+1}) \Big)^2 $$

The gradient of the objective is:

$$ \nabla_w L =  \Big( r_{t+1} + V_{w_{old}}(s_{t+1}) - V_w(s_t) \Big) \nabla_w V_w(s_t)$$

Now, if you approximate the value function with a linear approximator, i.e. $V_w(s_t) = w^T x(s_t)$, where $x(s_t)$ is a vector of (usually) handcrafted features, then you have $\nabla_w V_w(s_t) = x(s_t)$, and for the gradient of the objective you get:

\begin{align}
  \nabla_w L &= \Big( r_{t+1} + w^Tx(s_{t+1}) - w^Tx(s_t) \Big) x(s_t) \\
             &= r_{t+1} x(s_t) - w^T \Big(x(s_t) - x(s_{t+1}) \Big) x(s_t)  \\
             &= r_{t+1} x(s_t) - x(s_t) \Big(x(s_t) - x(s_{t+1}) \Big)^T w \\
             &= \textbf{b} - \textbf{A} w
\end{align}

Your gradient update rule would be:
$$ w_{new} = w + \alpha \nabla_w L = w + \alpha \Big(\textbf{b} - \textbf{A} w\Big) $$

Normally you would perform multiple time steps and at each step you will update the weights $w$. In LSTD, however, you perform multiple time steps, then you average $A$ and $b$ over these timesteps and then you compute the optimal $w$ with a single calculation by inverting $A$:
$$ w_{TD} = A^{-1}b $$

**UPDATE:**
To see where these "expecations" come from imagine that you rollout your policy for $T$ steps, that is you collect $T$ (state $s_t$, reward $r_{t+1}$, next state $s_{t+1}$) triples. For every triple you have to calculate the delta
$$\Delta w = r_{t+1} x(s_t) - x(s_t) \bigg( x(s_t)-x(s_{t+1}) \bigg)^T w$$
and update the weights $ w' = w + \alpha \Delta w$.

The optimal value of $w$ will be such that, after all updates are applied we have $w_{new} = w_{old}$. Thus, the sum of all updates has to be zero:
\begin{align}
  \sum_{(s_t, r_{t+1}, s_{t+1}) \in \mathcal{D}} \Delta w &= 0 \\
  \sum_{t=0}^T \Big( r_{t+1} x(s_t) - x(s_t) \bigg( x(s_t)-x(s_{t+1}) \bigg)^T w \Big) &= 0 \\
  \sum_{t=0}^{T} r_{t+1} x(s_t) - \sum_{t=0}^{T} x(s_t) \bigg( x(s_t)-x(s_{t+1}) \bigg)^T w &= 0 \\
  \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T} r_{t+1} x(s_t) - \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T} x(s_t) \bigg( x(s_t)-x(s_{t+1}) \bigg)^T w &= 0
\end{align}

On the last row we divide both sides of the equation by $T$. From here you can see that:
\begin{align}
  \textbf{b} &= \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=0}^{T} r_{t+1}x(s_t) \\
  &= \frac{1}{|\mathcal{D}|} \sum_{(s_t, r_{t+1}, s_{t+1}) \in \mathcal{D}} \Big[ r_{t+1} x(s_t) \Big] \\
  &= \mathbb{E}_{(s_t, r_{t+1}, s_{t+1}) \in \mathcal{D}} \Big[r_{t+1} x(s_t) \Big]
\end{align}

So $\textbf{b}$ is just the average of $ \bigg( r x(s) \bigg) $, which is by definition the expectation under the collected data.

For me the quantity $\sum_{t=0}^{T} r_{t+1}x(s_t)$ has much more meaning than this expectation. I think that they are using the expectation only to shorten the formula, but for me this is very misleading. Also they do not explicitly state **under what** is this expectation taken, which makes it even harder to read and understand.

Comment: I understood the dervication of A and b but I dont get how you can estimate E[R_t+1] as average of rewards from time 0 to t-1. Since each reward at each timestep may have a different distribution, wouldn't the estimate be incorrect?

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a vague understanding of expectations when it comes to stochastic random variables but your answer cleared it up. I agree that the formula in the book is very misleading. This is just one such case, there were other sections, for example, section 6.7 on maximisation bias.